# Formatting Date and Time in Jquery Template

Tags: datetime, jquery-templates

Can you please tell me how to format date with time in jquery template like this:

> 11/9/2011 12:00:00 AM

I am using this function which only formats the date part and hide the time portion of it:

```
function (jsonDate) {
    var value = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
    return value.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + value.getDate() + "/" + value.getFullYear();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
function (jsonDate) {
    var value = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
    return value.toUTCString();
}
```

You can see more options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743760%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)